# Symfony2 set user role on login

Tags: authentication, symfony, symfony-2.1

I want to use a single form to login normal users and admins, i have a flag on entity 'isAdmin'. If it's an admin redirect to panel and set ROLE_ADMIN, if not redirect to site and set ROLE_USER.

this is possible, have other method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the console commands for fosuserbundle, you can "promote" a user with the ROLE_ADMIN. On every login he'll be assigned with that role automatically.

It won't be working with a "isAdmin" flag on your Model Entity, more likely to use a mechanism provided by fosuserbundle itself (didn't dig into that myself to be honest).

You also might want to check out https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/groups.md

Comment: i dont use fosuserbundle on this app, is simple users ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: ah sorry, your question was tagged with fosuserbundle before.. sorry then :)

Answer (score 2):

That seems to make no sense at all.  You should set the user's role on registration not on login.

When user loggs in you can retrieve its object from database and get the role attribute to decide which view to load.